# How do I filter all 12 digit numbers in code?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello everyone and thank you for your time, my first post and I am a total newbie.

I'm trying to filter for any 12 digit number in column `B` to later cut them into another sheet named `PPE`.

How do I write a code to do that? In the sample below this works perfectly but only for `243080700547`.

I've provided a screenshot as well.

```
I = Worksheets("RAW DATA").UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = Worksheets("PPE").UsedRange.Rows.Count

If J = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("PPE").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
End If

Set xRg = Worksheets("RAW DATA").Range("C1:C" & I)

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "243080700547" Then
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("PPE").Range("A" & J + 1)
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete

        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "243080700547" Then
            K = K - 1
        End If

        J = J + 1
    End If
Next
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a cast to string through CStr so I'll assume that the values in column C are true numbers. In that case, a simple greater than/less than should suffice.

Work from the bottom to the top and you can avoid modifying the increment.

```
with Worksheets("RAW DATA")

  I = .cells(.rows.count, "C").end(xlup).row
  For K = I To 1 step -1
    If .cells(K, "C").value2 > 99999999999 And  .cells(K, "C").value2 <= 999999999999 Then
        J = J + 1
        .rows(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("PPE").Range("A" & J)
        .rows(K).EntireRow.delete
    End If
  Next K

end with
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it worked perfectly and I used this one. The only change I made to it was to make ...Range("A" & J) into ... Range("A" & J + 1)

Comment: As the first row was a heading and it was overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your first appereance of

`If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "243080700547" Then`

you can use

`If Len(CStr(xRg(K).Value)) = 12 Then`

to check if the string has a length of 12.

Question: Why do you check it a second time? You're already in the `If` block of that same (first) check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great, I do not know why it was repeated, I did not wrote that code, just copied it from someone elses code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter instead of looping through the whole date which could be a lot faster than copying row by row, because you copy all at once.

This will work for any other criteria too, you just need to adjust the `.AutoFilter`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim DestRow As Long 'find destination row
    DestRow = Worksheets("PPE").Cells(Worksheets("PPE").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With Worksheets("RAW DATA").UsedRange
        'filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=100000000000", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=999999999999"
        'copy date (without headers)
        .Resize(RowSize:=.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(RowOffset:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("PPE").Cells(DestRow, "A")
        'remove filter
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```